# forked execution breaks includeTargets in Grails _Events.groovy plugin

Tags: grails, plugins

seem to have more stupid issues with forked Execution in grails than anything else

using grails 2.4.4 on GGTS 3.6.3, groovy 2.3.7, 64bit

trying to repair another plugin (its out of date and i'm trying to fixit).  had problems.  pared all back to a simple plugin and demo project that includes the plugin from the local workspace

in DemoProject I do the local include of the plugin like this in buildConfig.groovy

```
grails.plugin.location.DummyPlugin = "../DummyPlugin"
```

so far so good.  without adding an _Events.grooy and running the DemoProject all starts ok and plugin loads.

now add an _Events.groovy to the plugins /script folder.  In that file I have this line right at top

```
import grails.util.BuildSettingsHolder as build
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsPackage")
```

now when you run the demo project you get an error like this

```
|Running Grails application
Error |
Error loading event script from file [E:\workspace\ggts3.6.2-workspace\DummyPlugin\scripts\_Events.groovy] No such property: classLoader for class: java.lang.Object (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: classLoader for class: java.lang.Object
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$1.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:409)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at _Events.run(_Events.groovy:29)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.createEventListener(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:147)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.createTomcatRunner(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:104)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.runInternal(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:82)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.run(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:66)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer.main(ForkedTomcatServer.groovy:60)
Error |
Error loading event script from file [E:\workspace\ggts3.6.2-workspace\DummyPlugin\scripts\_Events.groovy] No such property: classLoader for class: java.lang.Object
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/DemoDummyProject
```

if you got back to the DemoProject and stopped forked Execection by setting grails.project.fork =[] and run again it all works fine - no errors.

so essentially forked execution screws up the plugins includeTargets action.

how do you fix this whilst std forked config is now enabled as default - any clues?  advice requested

Comment: I tried to add the tomcat plugin to the plugin project and just tried to run the plugin directly with run-app - get the same problem - its the foreked execution that's messing something up. any ideas

Comment: You can disable forking, it's configured in BuildConfig.groovy. Replace the settings map with `false` for individual types (e.g. `run: false`), or comment out or delete the whole `grails.project.fork` block.

Comment: thanks burt - I did that and it worked - but the problem is that for myself and others when you create a project the forking is enabled - so I don't want to have to disable to get it to work

Comment: this looks like it was related to this other problem see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126532/grails-2-4-4-ggts-3-6-3-not-working-in-debug).  when I downloaded my new clean 3.6.3-sr1, and imported project from old to new workspace the includeTargets << grailsScripts(_GrailsPackage) line now seems to work.  i'm going to do some more testing on it (I've been trying to fix the activity plugin ) before posting back the fix to plugins site

Comment: @WILLIAMWOODMAN any update?