# Grails 2.4.4 GGTS 3.6.3 not working in debug

Tags: debugging, grails

bit more shinnangins

I have a project i'm trying to debug, using grails 2.4.4 and GGTS3.6.3

if run-app the project - works ok

when I try and set break point and the debug if get this error

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
Error |
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: argument type mismatch (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getForkConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1515)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.establishProjectStructure(BuildSettings.groovy:1389)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1121)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1116)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1088)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1074)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1054)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
Error |
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: argument type mismatch
```

this looks like a repeat of this link on earlier version of grails
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093259/grails-2-3-2-ggts-3-5-not-working-in-debug)

note says claimed fixed - but fails for me - any else got this issue

Comment: Disable Spring Loaded reloading with `-noreloading`

Comment: burt - missed this comment.  I did a brute force approach - I was using GGTS 3.6.2 which i'd allowed to upgrade to 3.6.3.    So this morning I went back to basics and downloaded a fresh GGTS3.6.3 build.  I then imported the project from previous workspace into a new workspace and tried again - and the problem appeared to disappeared.   I tried the -noreloading option in the previous build and it still failed just now - so I don't really know whats going on - but restarting in latest build and importing into new workspace has got me back up and moving, weird but there we go

Answer (score 1):

Brute force method.  download fresh 'latest' copy of GGTS (I did 3.6.3-sr1).  I then imported my project from previous workspace on 3.6.2 that i'd let get upgraded.

once imported into clean build and new workspace the problem seemed to go away.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem yesterday with ggts-3.4.0 and grails 2.4.3.

I can confirm that the -noreloading parameter has no effect.

I tried William's technique and implemented a clean install with ggts-3.6.4, alas to no avail.

In the end my solution/workaround is to leave one line of grails.project.fork uncommented out, namely:

```
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true]
```

This allows me to both: run ***and*** debug my Application.

Allan.